# Invalid Lateral for Float while scraping data with python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, finance

I am trying to import price of a stock from a website. It imports the price as a string but gives me below error when I try to change it to a float:

> ValueError: invalid literal for float()

This is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#<span class="current-price" style="color:#D22B00">1,780</span>

request = requests.get("http://www.sharesansar.com/company/EBL")

content = request.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

span_line = soup.find("span", {"class":"current-price", "style":"color:#D22B00"})

price = span_line.text.strip()

stock_price = float(price)
```

Comment: Can you put in a `print price` before the `float()`? What does it print out?

Comment: Before doing float(price), the variable price holds 1780 as a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
price = span_line.text.strip().replace(',', '')
```

`1,780` is invalid in python, get rid of the `,`

> class float([x])
>
> If the argument is a string, it should contain a decimal number,
>   optionally preceded by a sign, and optionally embedded in whitespace.
>   The optional sign may be '+' or '-'; a '+' sign has no effect on the
>   value produced.